# Not able to save to a created folder (applescript)

Tags: scripting, applescript

so I have been trying to create a script that will create a folder on my desktop, then create a spreadsheet, and save the spreadsheet to said folder. here is the script...

```
set folderName to "Tester"
set FileName to "MayDay"
set SaveName to FileName & ".numbers" as string
set FilePath to "Macintosh HD:Users:Ryan:Desktop:" & FileName & ":"
tell application "Finder" to make new folder at desktop with properties {name:folderName}
tell application "Numbers" to activate
tell application "Numbers" to make new document with properties {name:FileName}
tell application "Numbers"
    tell document 1
        tell table 1 of sheet 1
            merge range "B8:C8"
        end tell
    end tell

    delay 1
    tell application "Numbers" to activate
end tell
tell application "Numbers" to (save document 1) in FilePath
end
```

It has no problem making the folder, opening the spreadsheet, changing its name, and merging the cells, the problem comes in at the end when I try to save it.

I have tried adding (as numbers) no parenthesis after the save command, that errors out. After I run the script, and clear the crash, I can close out numbers and it will prompt me to save it in the "Tester" folder, but it won't do it on its own. insert grey hairs and headaches here.

I am really new to applescript, and I am hoping this is just a simple syntax thing, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's working code. A key is to use **POSIX path** and **POSIX file** and also the "save ... in ..." takes a *file reference*, not a string.

```
set folderName to "Tester"
set fileName to "MayDay.numbers"

set FilePath to (path to desktop as string) & folderName & ":" & fileName

set posixPath to POSIX path of FilePath

try
    tell application "Finder" to make new folder at desktop with properties {name:folderName}
on error errMsg
end try

tell application "Numbers"
    set myDoc to make new document with properties {name:fileName}
    tell myDoc
        tell table 1 of sheet 1
            merge range "B8:C8"
        end tell
    end tell

    delay 1

    save myDoc in POSIX file posixPath

end tell
```

Comment: This helped out lots, thank you!I Still don't understand a ton of the stuff I have put into my script, but Im failing forward with everyones help. I really appreciate it!